# Can't connect to Elasticsearch in OpenCTI stack docker install

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to make a Docker installation of OpenCTI work.

I've followed the instructions here https://github.com/OpenCTI-Platform/docker and I'm able to successfully create the Docker stack on Windows Desktop Docker.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

`

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.6
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.ml.enabled=false
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-10-13T00-23-17Z
    volumes:
      - s3data:/data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}    
    command: server /data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
    restart: always
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
    volumes:
      - amqpdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    restart: always
  opencti:
    image: opencti/platform:5.0.3
    environment:
      - NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8096
      - APP__PORT=8080
      - APP__ADMIN__EMAIL=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_EMAIL}
      - APP__ADMIN__PASSWORD=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - APP__ADMIN__TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - APP__APP_LOGS__LOGS_LEVEL=error
      - REDIS__HOSTNAME=redis
      - REDIS__PORT=6379
      - ELASTICSEARCH__URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - MINIO__ENDPOINT=minio
      - MINIO__PORT=9000
      - MINIO__USE_SSL=false
      - MINIO__ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      - MINIO__SECRET_KEY=${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - RABBITMQ__HOSTNAME=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ__PORT=5672
      - RABBITMQ__PORT_MANAGEMENT=15672
      - RABBITMQ__MANAGEMENT_SSL=false
      - RABBITMQ__USERNAME=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ__PASSWORD=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      - SMTP__HOSTNAME=${SMTP_HOSTNAME}
      - SMTP__PORT=25
      - PROVIDERS__LOCAL__STRATEGY=LocalStrategy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
      - minio
      - rabbitmq
    restart: always
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==manager"
  worker:
    image: opencti/worker:5.0.3
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - WORKER_LOG_LEVEL=info
    depends_on:
      - opencti
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    restart: always
  connector-history:
    image: opencti/connector-history:5.0.3
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_HISTORY_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=STREAM
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=History
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=history
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-export-file-stix:
    image: opencti/connector-export-file-stix:5.0.3
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_EXPORT_FILE_STIX_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_EXPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ExportFileStix2
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=application/json
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-export-file-csv:
    image: opencti/connector-export-file-csv:5.0.3
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_EXPORT_FILE_CSV_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_EXPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ExportFileCsv
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=text/csv
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-import-file-stix:
    image: opencti/connector-import-file-stix:5.0.3
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_IMPORT_FILE_STIX_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_IMPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ImportFileStix
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=application/json,text/xml
      - CONNECTOR_AUTO=false # Enable/disable auto-import of file
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-import-report:
    image: opencti/connector-import-report:5.0.3
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=${OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN}
      - CONNECTOR_ID=${CONNECTOR_IMPORT_REPORT_ID} # Valid UUIDv4
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=INTERNAL_IMPORT_FILE
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=ImportReport
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=application/pdf,text/plain
      - CONNECTOR_AUTO=false # Enable/disable auto-import of file
      - CONNECTOR_ONLY_CONTEXTUAL=true # Only extract data related to an entity (a report, a threat actor, etc.)
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
      - IMPORT_REPORT_CREATE_INDICATOR=false
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - opencti
  connector-alienvault:
    image: opencti/connector-alienvault:5.0.3
    environment:
      - OPENCTI_URL=http://opencti:8080
      - OPENCTI_TOKEN=2cf0a4fe-4ded-4931-901b-20e599b7f013
      - CONNECTOR_ID=0c02a154-95a5-4624-b1cd-225582c12975
      - CONNECTOR_TYPE=EXTERNAL_IMPORT
      - CONNECTOR_NAME=AlienVault
      - CONNECTOR_SCOPE=alienvault
      - CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=15 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
      - CONNECTOR_UPDATE_EXISTING_DATA=false
      - CONNECTOR_LOG_LEVEL=info
      - ALIENVAULT_BASE_URL=https://otx.alienvault.com
      - ALIENVAULT_API_KEY=8f261df53d1d06c095edcd6a4b6677a6f46f72cdfcbbc4e2794758b7dca1a51d
      - ALIENVAULT_TLP=White
      - ALIENVAULT_CREATE_OBSERVABLES=true
      - ALIENVAULT_CREATE_INDICATORS=true
      - ALIENVAULT_PULSE_START_TIMESTAMP=2021-05-01T00:00:00                  # BEWARE! Could be a lot of pulses!
      - ALIENVAULT_REPORT_TYPE=threat-report
      - ALIENVAULT_REPORT_STATUS=New
      - ALIENVAULT_GUESS_MALWARE=false                                        # Use tags to guess malware.
      - ALIENVAULT_GUESS_CVE=true                                             # Use tags to guess CVE.
      - ALIENVAULT_EXCLUDED_PULSE_INDICATOR_TYPES=FileHash-MD5,FileHash-SHA1  # Excluded Pulse indicator types.
      - ALIENVAULT_ENABLE_RELATIONSHIPS=true                                  # Enable/Disable relationship creation between SDOs.
      - ALIENVAULT_ENABLE_ATTACK_PATTERNS_INDICATES=true                      # Enable/Disable "indicates" relationships between indicators and attack patterns
      - ALIENVAULT_INTERVAL_SEC=1800
    restart: always
volumes:
  esdata:
  s3data:
  redisdata:
  amqpdata:
```

`

and here is my .env file

`

```
OPENCTI_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@opencti.io
OPENCTI_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
OPENCTI_ADMIN_TOKEN=2cf0a4fe-4ded-4931-901b-20e599b7f013
MINIO_ROOT_USER=RootUser
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=RootPassword
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=DefaultUser
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=DefaultPass
CONNECTOR_HISTORY_ID=168b9e3f-cbb4-4d06-91d8-073a20ce2453
CONNECTOR_EXPORT_FILE_STIX_ID=a1fed5cb-0b60-4756-95b0-f62fb67204af
CONNECTOR_EXPORT_FILE_CSV_ID=3bbb35ef-2168-4031-832b-451767f6715c
CONNECTOR_IMPORT_FILE_STIX_ID=53bf4c37-f196-401e-af63-e4a0e7194c2b
CONNECTOR_IMPORT_REPORT_ID=11c03aeb-8b8a-4c95-a531-f82b0aebb2ad
SMTP_HOSTNAME=172.17.0.1
```

`

After creating my Docker stack as I'm unable to connect to localhost:8080 I looked at the logs of the opencti/platform container and I get the following error

```
{"error":{"name":"ConfigurationError","_error":{},"_showLocations":false,"_showPath":false,"time_thrown":"2021-11-10T16:09:02.791Z","data":{"reason":"ElasticSearch seems down","http_status":500,"category":"technical","error":"connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.3:9200"},"internalData":{}},"category":"APP","version":"5.0.3","level":"error","message":"[OPENCTI] Platform initialization fail","timestamp":"2021-11-10T16:09:02.793Z"}


/opt/opencti/build/src/config/errors.js:8

  return new Exception();

         ^

ConfigurationError: A configuration error has occurred

    at error (/opt/opencti/build/src/config/errors.js:8:10)

    at ConfigurationError (/opt/opencti/build/src/config/errors.js:53:3)

    at /opt/opencti/build/src/database/elasticSearch.js:190:15

    at process.async (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

    at checkSystemDependencies (/opt/opencti/build/src/initialization.js:113:40)

    at initialization (/opt/opencti/build/src/initialization.js:372:3)

    at /opt/opencti/build/src/boot.js:7:16
```

which says that OpenCTI is unable to connect with the elasticsearch container.

Running curl on the host machine returns the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty"
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

and running curl inside the elastic search container returns the following:

```
sh-4.4# curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

And finally here is the output of the Elastic container log

```
c:\Tools\OpenCTI\docker>docker logs docker_elasticsearch_1
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch (file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-7.15.1.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security (file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-7.15.1.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:12:49,261Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "version[7.15.1], pid[8], build[default/docker/83c34f456ae29d60e94d886e455e6a3409bba9ed/2021-10-07T21:56:19.031608185Z], OS[Linux/5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Adoptium/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/17/17+35]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:12:50,963Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk], using bundled JDK [true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:12:50,965Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-3486636715162729323, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms3170m, -Xmx3170m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1661992960, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:24:45,864Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:24:45,937Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "loaded module [analysis-common]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:24:45,937Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.p.PluginsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "loaded module [constant-keyword]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:28:55,893Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [40.5s/40538938900ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:28:56,461Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [21.1s/21140ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:29:09,291Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [21.1s/21189926100ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:29:09,730Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [13.2s/13272ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:29:09,808Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [13.2s/13271423200ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:29:40,059Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [21s/21002ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:29:41,083Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [21s/21002782100ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:31:25,568Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [1.3m/80947ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:31:27,646Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [1.3m/80946985800ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:40:11,402Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [11.9s/11968ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:40:16,415Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [11.9s/11967222000ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:40:17,438Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [6s/6050ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:40:17,489Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [6s/6050442500ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:42:07,964Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [9.1s/9115ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:42:08,922Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [9.1s/9115088600ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:44:45,356Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@3eac944, interval=5s}] took [6225ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:44:45,139Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [6.2s/6226ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:44:45,809Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [6.2s/6225665000ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:44:57,124Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [6.7s/6719ms] on absolute clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:44:57,488Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "timer thread slept for [6.7s/6718734700ns] on relative clock which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-11-10T16:44:57,181Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.t.ThreadPool", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "329e6b6ab306", "message": "execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@4e9331e8, interval=1m}] took [6718ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]" }
```

Docker version is the following

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:58:50 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.8
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.6
  Git commit:       75249d8
  Built:            Fri Jul 30 19:52:31 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.9
  GitCommit:        e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.1
  GitCommit:        v1.0.1-0-g4144b63
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I don't have the faintest clue of what's going on! Please help!

Thank you in advance!

P.S. - I tried to use Elasticsearch's docker-compose.yml file to start another stack

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.1
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.1
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

and I'm receiving the same error

Please find the attached Diagnostics ID from docker

```
8A8E051B-440A-45B6-8AFC-1DCB7BB07FF3/20211110173108
```